# Orchestrator or coordination pattern in Azure?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns, enterprise-architecture

I am designing a background web job in Azure that, given a list of users it retrieves from a database, makes calls to a separate messaging microservice (for each record) that will end up sending N number of email/SMS for each call that was made to it.

Say, for 10,000 users, I make 10,000 calls to the messaging service. All those 10,000 calls also carry a the same Batch Identifier, which the messaging system saves.

Once the messaging microservice finishes processing all of the 10k calls, I need to call it back with the Batch Identifier, for it to tell me how many messages it ended up sending for the whole batch.

I'm having trouble finding the right approach or pattern for determining when to call back for the final result of the whole batch.

I can think of a few different approaches, but not sure which of these is better, or if there's a better option.

1. Have a separate batch job that is looks for pending batches that fires every X number of minutes and checks with the messaging system, until it receives confirmation that all records are processed and provides the numbers. Then send the email.
2. Fire maybe a durable function that keeps calling the messaging service every X seconds or minutes until the messaging service says the records are processed.
3. Callbacks...ugliest option. Messaging service is generic so should be the least possible aware of its consumers.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.